# 'Controller' is a namespace but is used like a type error on compiling an ASP.NET core application

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an empty asp.net core app. I have added a controller to the application. When I try to compile the application it throws the below error

'Controller' is a namespace but is used like a type

The source is below

[image]

However if I prefix Controller with the namespace as shown below then it works fine.

[image]

Why is this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your namespace, `WebApplication1.Controller`.  Compiler thinks you want that instead of the `Controller` class.  Rename your directory and namespace to be plural `Controllers` as is the usual practice and you won't have this issue.